# When the file selected for upload, livewire component is automatically rendering

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Is there any possibility to stop Livewire rendering on each click event?

Actualy The issue is, if any event triggered from HTML or Javascript, then the render function automatically called from Livewire component in Laravel.

It seems if any third party tool initialized in HTML then it will again triggered the render function.

How to avoid this? Any help

Answer (score 0):

In such case, you need to use [Deferred Updating](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#deferred-updating).

in cases where you don't need data updates to happen live, Livewire has a `.defer` modifer that batches data updates with the next network request.

For example, given the following component:

```
<input type="text" wire:model.defer="query">
<button wire:click="search">Search</button>
```

As the user types into the  field, no network requests will be sent. Even if the user clicks away from the input field and onto other fields on the page, no requests will be sent.

When the user presses "Search", Livewire will send ONE network request that contains both the new "query" state, AND the "search" action to perform.

This can drastically cut down on network usage when it's not needed.

Comment: It is ok for textbox input. But if you click the "search" button, again livewire will render entire page.So it should not happen.

Comment: In such case add `type="button"` and remove the wirw:click event. That way the default submit will not take place.

Comment: Actualy my issue is, If we make any call to the Livewire componant, addionaly it will call  "render" function. For example,There are two functions in Livewire componant class. One is  "search" and another is "render". So if we call "search" function from HTML page,   also finaly it will trigger the "render" function. This is the issue.

Comment: This is an expected behaviour. Else, instead of livewire component you can use blade component https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components

Answer (score 0):

use prevent event modifier inside the button

```
<input type="text" name="text_field_name" wire:model.defer="search_txt" />
<button type="button" wire:click.prevent="yourFunction">Seacrh</button>
```